# Show information and upload new record into MySQL table after submit form in while loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, loops, form-submit

Im displaying some mysql records in php loop while each of this record has the own form. I want to upload some data in mysql table and then show information that data was sent properly after clicking on desired submit button. 
Informations are hidden in two divs - "successReport" and "errorReport".
My code in PHP looks similiar to:

```
while(){
    echo '<div class="someRow">
        <div>here i display record form mysql table<div>
        <div><form>here is my form with submit button</form></div>
        <div>here are my submit informations</div>
        </div>';
}
```

Data upload works perfectly, but my problem is - after clicking on submit button, the information div is displayed in all visible rows and not for only one (chosen by me).

This is the script I use inside a loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.lanparty_<?php echo $oferta['klucz']; ?>').on('submit',function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url:'lanpartyZgloszenie.php',
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                type:'POST',
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $(this).next('.successReport').fadeIn('slow');
                },
                error:function(data){
                    $(this).next('.errorReport').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); 


        });
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: `if($result){ echo "DB successfully written to."; } else{ echo "Sorry"; }`

Comment: thanks, but this is not im asking for, my problem is that divs described as class="successReport" or "errorReport" are shown in all rows but not in the only one where submit button was clicked.

Comment: Then you need to take it out of your `while` loop and just use the loop to fetch the results, then display it outside of it.

Comment: i know what you mean, but this is still not the solution i need.
For example i fetch results with form (hidden values) and submit buttons, like here - http://i.imgur.com/h3sNf9r.png

Now i want to display this 2 divs (success/error) in each row where the submit button was clicked (without the page refresh) :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to be able to think of a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put an id + an index to your successReport and errorReport div/s ..
just as what you did on your div  --- $('.lanparty_') ---

example on your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lanparty_<?php echo $oferta['klucz']; ?>').on('submit',function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'lanpartyZgloszenie.php',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $(this).next('.successReport<?php echo $oferta['klucz']';?>).fadeIn('slow');
            },
            error:function(data){
                $(this).next('.errorReport<?php echo $oferta['klucz']';?>).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); 


    });
});
</script>



 hope my idea could help ..
```